# Angularjs exclusive radio buttons in table row

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, tablerow

I am using angularjs v1.

I would like to have exclusive radio buttons in each table row. Each row will look something like below;

[image]

The radio buttons should be exclusive. In other words, only 1 of the buttons can be selected at any one time. When the `send radio button info` button is pressed, information regarding which radio button is selected should be sent to the angularjs controller.

Here is my html code;

```
<div ng-controller="RadioButtonsCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover data-table sort display">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="Off_">
                Off
            </th>
            <th class="On_">
                On
            </th>
            <th class="Toggle_">
                Middle
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in radio_button_items">
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_off"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_on"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_middle"></td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="SendInfo(item)">Send radio button info</button>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the controller code;

```
.controller('RadioButtonsCtrl', ['$scope', 
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.SendInfo = function (row) {
                    console.log(row);
                }           
        }])
```

Comment: give a `name`prop to each radio button in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Radio button groups* are defined by giving them the same `name` attribute:

```
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_off" name="foo"></td>
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_on" name="foo"></td>
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="model.select_middle" name="foo"></td>
```

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type

> radio: A radio button. You must use the value attribute to define the
>   value submitted by this item. Use the checked attribute to indicate
>   whether this item is selected by default. **Radio buttons that have the
>   same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio button
>   group". Only one radio button in a group can be selected at a time.**